# Magento 2.3 Bosnian language pack not working

Tags: magento2, multistore, language-package

I have installed Mageplaza's Bosnian language pack. I have set a store configuration local to Bosnian, but on the frontend, English is still shown. Also, I tried changing the admin locale, but that too not changing the language in the admin.
screenshot: https://nimb.ws/hZVOTL, https://nimb.ws/jRL7bY
Does anyone have idea? A cache is also cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Inchoo Croatian language pack in app/code/i18n and set language to Croatian. There is not much difference in Bosnian and Croatian languages.